# Open a downloaded html file with WebView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-webview

I have an app that opens certain webpages with webview. If there is internet connection, the webview opens a certain url and downloads html file. If there is no internet connection, the webview is supposed to open the previously downloaded html file.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
webView.loadUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.whizzapps.stpsurniki/" + razred + ".html");
```

The path is 100% right, but it still won't show it for some reason. I did some research and I saw that people usually put the downloaded html file in assets folder, but I'm downloading the html file inside application so I don't really have access to assets folder. What should I do?

Comment: If you open a browser on the device, and enter the URL that gets passed to the loadURL function.. what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use loadData instead, but you need to read the file first:

```
data = readFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.whizzapps.stpsurniki/" + razred + ".html");
webView.loadData(data, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
//or 
//webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, result, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, null);
```

here is a function to read the file

```
private String readFile(String path) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try
    {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        br.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```